# How can I automate the generation of a powerpoint with python

Tags: python, powerpoint

Let's say I have a list of students (names) and their corresponding photos, as well as some grades for the students. How can I insert the student's desired photo as a background picture for some or all of the slides, insert their names on JUST the title slide and insert their grades on select slides?

How should I go about this in python if I want to edit a base template powerpoint for each student with their corresponding information?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This isn't a place to get free application design or tutorials.  Do you have a Python package picked out that helps you do this?  Does that package work on its own or does it work with a Powerpoint app?  You need to first pick the package you'll use to do this (I assume there is at least one.). Then you need to study that package's documentation to work out all of the steps needed to do what you want to do.  This is programming.  If you want to be a programmer, doing this sort of research and study is a big part of that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python-pptx library. It is a Python library for creating and updating PowerPoint (.pptx) files.

This includes:

Round-trip any Open XML presentation (.pptx file) including all its elements
Add slides
Populate text placeholders, for example to create a bullet slide
Add image to slide at arbitrary position and size
Add textbox to a slide; manipulate text font size and bold
Add table to a slide
Add auto shapes (e.g. polygons, flowchart shapes, etc.) to a slide
Add and manipulate column, bar, line, and pie charts
Access and change core document properties such as title and subject

Link for download: https://pypi.org/project/python-pptx/

Link for documentation: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!